# Register two Java web applications with Spring Registry

Tags: cloud-foundry, netflix-eureka, cfnetworking

I want to register two sample Java web applications with Spring Registry so that both applications can communicate directly. I don't know much about programming.

Here I found the [Spring Registry code](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/cf-networking-release/tree/develop/src/example-apps/eureka/registry), where [Spring backend](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/cf-networking-release/tree/develop/src/example-apps/eureka/backend) application is registering itself when it is deployed on Cloud Foundry, so that any Spring frontend application that is trying to reach the backend can communicate directly.

How can I register a simple Java dynamic web application to make direct communication between them without using the third-party services like [RabbitMQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RabbitMQ)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are misunderstanding the use cases. The Netflix Eureka registry is for service registry that helps facilitate service to service communication.

Suppose a service - `abc.foo.com` and it needs to call another service `pqr.foo.com`. You don't want the path for the `pqr` service hardcoded in the `abc` service. Hardcoding like is an anti-pattern for cloud native applications. The approach is to have service `abc` and `pqr` register themselves with a service registry (eureka, consul, etc.). Then at runtime, the service, `abc` here, can interrogate registry and get an active instance of the `pqr` service and invoke it.

For your Java web applications, that need to call each other, I am assuming, all your interactions (service calls) are done on server-side. In which case, using Eureka registry, one microservice an easily find and get instance of another service and invoke it. You don't need RabbitMQ for that.

I would recommend looking at the [jHipster](https://jhipster.github.io/microservices-architecture/) project. It is an open source project. They have a Eureka based registry service, a gateway service, microservices and client-side UI (Node.js).

It will be a good starting point and there is a lot of open source help available.

I hope this helps!